# c#: How to use struct with field initializers as dictionary value

Tags: c#, struct

The structure is always initialized by default if it is not found in the dictionary by TryGetValue.

```
internal class Program {

    struct Test {
        public int a = 10;
        public Test() { }
    }

    static Dictionary<int, Test> map = new Dictionary<int, Test>();

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Console.WriteLine(new Test().a); // print 10: OK
        map.TryGetValue(0, out Test test);
        Console.WriteLine(test.a);  // print 0: NOT WORKED!
    }
}
```

This behavior is indeed is expected: [structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct)

> The most common situation where you'll see default values is in arrays or in other collections where internal storage includes blocks of variables.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to achieve? Clearly you should not be ignoring result of `TryGetValue`, but that is probably not what you are looking for... I've also edited the post to clarify that you know that the behavior is expected...

Comment: I want the structure to always be initialized with the expected value and not look for bugs in my program...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only answer than is "use class"... There are way too many cases where `default(T)` is returned for `struct` values and you either have to know all the cases when default can be returned or switch to classes (also those still have `null` problem :(.

Comment: @PaulF I believe the bit you're missing is that `new Test()` and `default(Test)` now may return different things, which was not the case before field initializers in structs were allowed in C# 10.0.

Comment: This isn't quite true @GSerg. Even in older versions of C#, a value set to the field in the constructor is not applied with `default(Test)` because the constructor is never invoked. Essentially, initialization is _NOT_ run with `default`, hence the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, `TryGetValue` will return `default(TValue)` if the entry is not found, which for a struct includes the fields holding their default values.

You can easily replicate this behavior by expanding your test:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Test().a); // print 10: OK
map.TryGetValue(0, out Test test);
Console.WriteLine(test.a);  // print 0: NOT WORKED!
Console.WriteLine(default(Test).a); // print 0
```

As a result, if you want to ensure that `test` is always properly initialized, you should check the boolean result of `TryGetValue` and initialize the value if it is false:

```
Test test;

if (!map.TryGetValue(0, out test))
{
    test = new();
}

Console.WriteLine(test.a);
```